# PHP: Check if link is image and check if exists

Tags: php, arrays, string

i try to check if image exists and when i execute code say "Not Image".

```
if(@is_array(getimagesize("https://media.giphy.com/media/BvvBz8BnRqZOg/giphy.gif"))) {
    echo "Work";
} else {
  echo "Not Image";
}
```

Where is problem, Thanks in advance !

Comment: Well, I could run this code here. What happens if curl this url? Also, I don't think you need `is_array`, because `getimagesize` returns false when your parameter is not an image or is unavailable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try

```
$headers = get_headers('https://media.giphy.com/media/BvvBz8BnRqZOg/giphy.gif', 1);
if (strpos($headers['Content-Type'], 'image/') !== false) {
    echo "Work";
} else {
    echo "Not Image";
}
```

You only need to check the headers to see it it is an image, $headers['Content-Type'] in the example is 'image/gif' which is caught by the if statement. For reference check out get headers in the docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php

Comment: WoW Work Perfect Thank You So Much

Comment: I suppose `!==` is a typo ?